# Unable to login after dd clone

Tags: dd, clone

I have a test system with two 80GB drives:  /dev/sda has Windows7 installed on it and /dev/sdb has Ubuntu 14.04.  I imaged the Ubuntu drive to a third USB HDD using
    dd if=/dev/sdb of=/media/usb250GB/image.dd
then physically removed the /dev/sdb drive and replaced it with another 80GB drive.  I booted the Ubuntu 14.04 LiveCD and restored the image with dd if=/media/usb250GB/image.dd of=/dev/sdb .

Now the system boots properly but I'm unable to log in:  I enter my username and password, then the screen flashes and I'm dumped back at the login screen.  I can repeat this as many times as I like to make sure I'm not mistyping my password.  A search for this problem suggests I need to fix the UUIDs in /etc/fstab and /boot/grub/grub.cfg but blkid suggests that the values in there are correct.  I assume the difference is that I had selected "Encrypt home directory" when I installed.  Any suggestions on what I need to fix to be able to log in using the cloned drive?

Comment: could you login through tty? press ctrl+Alt+F1 and try to login via tty. What is happening?

Comment: I am able to login via tty and my home directory is there so I guess X is crashing and kicking me back out.  Where do I check next?  I'm a noob at interpreting the logs...